# Segmentation fault in memory allocation when making a dynamically resized array C++

Tags: c++, inheritance, segmentation-fault, polymorphism

I get a segmentation fault when the `append(int val)` function is run, and called polymorphically, but I can't see where the memalloc error is coming from. I'm still new to C++, and run into this problem a lot, but when I do fix it on my own, it's always by happenchance. Any pointer? (No pun intended, or is it :))

IntegerCombination.h

```
#ifndef INTEGERCOMBINATION_H
#define INTEGERCOMBINATION_H


using namespace std;

class IntegerCombination
{
public:
    IntegerCombination();
    void append(int Val);
    virtual int combine() = 0;
protected:
    int* _collection;
    int _length;
};

#endif
```

IntegerCombination.cpp

```
#include "IntegerCombination.h"

IntegerCombination::IntegerCombination()
{
    _length = 0;
}

void IntegerCombination::append(int val)
{
    int newValPos = _length;            // Stores current length as new position for new 
                                        // value
    int* temp = _collection;            //Stores current array
    delete _collection;                 // Deletes current array
    _length++;                          // Increases the length for the new array
    _collection = new int[_length];     // Creates a new array with the new length
    for(int i = 0; i < newValPos; i++)
    {
        _collection[i] = temp[i];       // Allocates values from old array into new array
    }
    _collection[newValPos] = val;       // Appends new value onto the end of the new array
}
```

Main.cpp

```
#include "IntegerCombination.h"
#include "ProductCombination.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{

    ProductCombination objProd;

    for(int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
    {
        objProd.append(i);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Note: The code in ProductCombination.h and ProductCombination.cpp is not entirely relevant, as in the .cpp file, `append(int val)` is only delegating the append call to the base class in IntegerCombination.h

Comment: There are several mistakes here. First, is using `delete` with `new[]`. You need to use `delete[]` instead. Second, you try to use `temp` which points to an array that you just tried to `delete`. You need to copy the elements before deleting them. Third, your type doesn't follow the [Rule of 3/5/0](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three). Any of these mistakes could cause a seg fault on its own.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux Please add answer, to Andog can accept that.

Comment: The real mistake is with the teacher (assuming this is an excercise) for not teaching about std::vector first.

Comment: @PepijnKramer we went over std::vector in the first semester, but our lecturer wants us to use pointers as first years, then once he understand whats going on in terms of memory allocation, and how it all works, we can move on to std::vector

Comment: Unrelated: If you have not already, familiarize yourself with [the Rules of Three, Five, and Zero](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three). You'll save yourself a ton of debugging.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For starters the constructor does not initializes the data member `_collection`

```
IntegerCombination::IntegerCombination()
{
    _length = 0;
}
```

So this data member can have an indeterminate value and using the operator delete with such a pointer invokes undefined bejavior.

Moreover as you are trying to allocate an array then you need to use the operator `delete []` instead of `delete`.

And the class has to define explicitly at least a virtual destructor. Also either declare the copy constructor and the copy assignment operator as deleted or also define them explicitly.

The function `append` has several bugs.

As it was mentioned you need to use the operator `delete []` in this statement

```
delete _collection;
```

instead of the operator `delete`.

But this operator must be called after the new array is allocated. Otherwise the pointer `temp` will have an invalid value

```
int* temp = _collection;            //Stores current array
delete [] _collection;                 // Deletes current array
```

That is you need to delete the previous array after you copied elements of it to the new allocated array.

Comment: How would I go about initializing _collection if it starts with 0 elements?

Comment: @Andog Initialize it with the literal nullptr. For example _collection = nullptr;